# Policy when reviewing Tag Wiki edits - plagiarism of unique info vs. general common definitions?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I ran across a situation where a user was suggesting Tag Wiki edit for **specification pattern** where a quick check disclosed the probable source to be Wikipedia. The question arose:

**How should I handle approving or rejecting what was clearly a copy/paste -- but of what amounts to nothing more than a common definition within the body of common knowledge?**

Obviously when reviewing if some obscure bit of unique information raises the **Is it plagiarized?** question, finding a source that should have received attribution would prompt a reject. But what about those edits that propose what amounts to a standard definition that can be found in multiple sources with identical (or substantially similar) text?

Answer (score 5):

Extensive common knowledge has no place in tag wikis; they should at most contain a concise description of the subject to help confirm you have picked the right topic.

The goal of a tag wiki is to help users figure out *when to use the tag*. From the [original feature announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/):

> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain frequently asked questions about the tag and guidelines on its usage.

and from a blog post about a [redesign of the feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/):

> It is my strong belief that the tags page is **an essential map of what your community is, and is not, about**.

The tag wiki should describe what the tag wiki is for, *in the context of Stack Overflow*. This doesn't mean you need to describe the subject in detail, just enough so that users of Stack Overflow can determine if they have the correct tag or not.

To further that goal, adding in links to commonly asked questions in the tag is helpful, as is what other tags to combine it with.

Tag edits that don't align with that goal should be rejected. Knowledge that is available elsewhere, especially when there are multiple sources, should at best be summarised.